# form_valid causes TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Tags: django, django-views

I have based my formset on the CRUD methodology. Taken code from here and there. I can't understand the Error that it is producing:

```
Internal Server Error: /create/(?P2[\w-]+)/$
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Projects\hosp_app\doc_aide\views.py", line 84, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 126, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 57, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 465, in __init__
    self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 147, in iri_to_uri
    return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 853, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 878, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

The Formset class on which it is based is as follows:

The form and view are as below:

```py
class PrescriptionCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Prescription
    template_name = 'doc_aide/write_prescription4.html'
    form_class = PrescriptionForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print('here')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['line_prescription'] = SinglePrescriptionFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['line_prescription'] = SinglePrescriptionFormset()
        context['form'].fields['patient'].initial = Patient.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['patient'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('Ia am here')
        context = self.get_context_data()
        prescriptionlines = context['line_prescription']
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            if prescriptionlines.is_valid():
                prescriptionlines.instance = self.object
                prescriptionlines.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('doc_aide:prescription_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `get_success_url` method you are returning a url using `reverse_lazy`, which returns an object, `get_success_url` is supposed to return a **string**. You should use `reverse` instead:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('doc_aide:prescription_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Also in your form valid method at the end you are using `return super().form_valid(form)` which might cause some trouble for you, as the form_valid method of the super class **will also** save the form. Instead change it to `return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())`.