# NoReverseMatch at /34/order/update/

Tags: python, django

**Problem:** When updating a form, I`ve got the following error:

```
Reverse for 'detail_order' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 34}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<purchaseorder_id>[0-9]+)/detail_order$']
```

**Error:** The error comes from the way how I am writing the get_success_url and the url.

```
def get_success_url(self):
   return reverse_lazy('accounting:detail_order', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

How can I modify my view to link pk to purchaseorder_id?

**views.py**

```
class OrderUpdate(UpdateView):  
    model = PurchaseOrder
    template_name = 'accounting/orders/edit_order.html'
    form_class = PurchaseOrderForm
    success_url = None
  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(OrderUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['lines'] = OrderLineFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['lines'] = OrderLineFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        lines = context['lines']
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()
            if lines.is_valid():
                lines.instance = self.object
                lines.save()
        return super(OrderUpdate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounting:detail_order', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
    
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OrderUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def detail_order(request, purchaseorder_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, pk=purchaseorder_id)
    orderlines = OrderLine.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounting/orders/order_detail.html', {'order': order, 'orderlines': orderlines})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<purchaseorder_id>[0-9]+)/detail_order$', views.detail_order, name='detail_order'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern expects a keyword argument `purchaseorder_id`, yet you pass it `pk`. Furthermore you override `get_success_url` yet you are using `reverse_lazy` this might give you an error depending upon the Django version (appears to be fixed in recent versions) because `get_success_url` is supposed to return a **string** (`reverse_lazy` returns a lazy object). Change your `get_success_url` like so:

```py
from django.urls import reverse


def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('accounting:detail_order', kwargs={'purchaseorder_id': self.object.pk})
```

Comment: @Alasdair I have seen a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979551/form-valid-causes-typeerror-quote-from-bytes-expected-bytes) where this was causing an error. Also if you see the builtin implementation of `get_success_url` it returns the url in this fashion `return str(self.success_url)  # success_url may be lazy`,

Comment: @Alasdair although looking at the [code here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/23fa29f6a6659e0f600d216de6bcb79e7f6818c9/django/utils/encoding.py#L127-L128) it seems that this is a solved issue so you are correct for at least recent versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's interesting. I have recommended switching `reverse_lazy` to `reverse` many times when the lazy version isn't required, but I had never come across `reverse_lazy` causing errors in some Django versions.